# Flask and Tornado Applciation does not handle multiple concurrent requests

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I am running a simple Flask app with Tornado, but the view only handles one request at a time.  How can I make it handle multiple concurrent requests?

The fix I'm using is to fork and use the multiple processes to handle requests, but I don't like that solution.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/flask')
def hello_world():
    return 'This comes from Flask ^_^'

from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import FallbackHandler, RequestHandler, Application
from flasky import app

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("This message comes from Tornado ^_^")

tr = WSGIContainer(app)

application = Application([
    (r"/tornado", MainHandler),
    (r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=tr)),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 3):

The immediate answer is that you should use a dedicated WSGI server, such as uWSGI or Gunicorn, and configure it to use multiple workers. Do not Tornado as a WSGI server.

---

Your fix of spawning processes is correct in as much as using WSGI with Tornado is "correct".  WSGI is a synchronous protocol: one worker handles one request at a time.  Flask doesn't know about Tornado, so it can't play nice with it by using coroutines: handling the request happens synchronously.

[Tornado has a big warning in their docs about this exact thing.](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#running-wsgi-apps-on-tornado-servers)

> WSGI is a *synchronous* interface, while Tornado’s concurrency model is based on single-threaded asynchronous execution. This means that running a WSGI app with Tornado’s `WSGIContainer` is *less scalable* than running the same app in a multi-threaded WSGI server like [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or [uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Use `WSGIContainer` only when there are benefits to combining Tornado and WSGI in the same process that outweigh the reduced scalability.

In other words: to handle more concurrent requests with a WSGI application, spawn more workers.  The type of worker also matters: threads vs. processes vs. eventlets all have tradeoffs.  You're spawning workers by creating processes yourself, but it's more common to use a WSGI server such as uWSGI or Gunicorn.