# What is the proper way to thread tornado+flask app?

Tags: python, web, flask, tornado

I made a web app with flask and ran it with flask's own web server with parameter 'threaded=True'. It worked perfectly.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)
```

But sooner I've found that it's only suitable for dev environment, so I decided to use 'tornado'. But it doesn't work concurrently.

```
http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Is there any parameter like 'threaded=True' of flask to thread? Or should I do it manually? If so, what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Here is a helpful link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644247/flask-and-tornado-applciation-does-not-handle-multiple-concurrent-requests

Comment: Flask on Tornado will give you a far worse performance than a single threaded Flask app without Tornado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado's WSGIContainer does not support threads, which means that it is also not suitable for most production usage (the rest of Tornado is, just not WSGIContainer). It's only a good idea to use Tornado's WSGIContainer when it's important to serve both Tornado RequestHandlers and WSGI applications in the same process. Otherwise, I recommend `gunicorn` or `uwsgi`.